# QML TextArea baseline

Tags: qt, qml

how can i remove the line which appears under a text area in qml? is it even possible? because groove music has such a thing without a line! what is that?
if not what other component should i use instead?

thanks in advance

```
TextArea{
            id:search
            placeholderText: qsTr("Search")
            x:7
            width: parent.width - 25
            onFocusChanged: border.color= "gray"

        }
```

(as in groove music search box or telegram which has no line and only a place holder text)

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: What Qt version? What OS? What a line? I have no line in me `TextArea`.

Comment: 5.9 - windows - can't upload image to show you what i mean

Comment: If you can not upload it directly here upload it to another place and share the link

Comment: https://ibb.co/eBYUpa - check it here

Comment: You could share a reproducible and complete example, since I have executed the code and it does not generate that error

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That looks like the Material style. You can disable the line by setting the [`background`](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtquickcontrols2.git/tree/src/imports/controls/material/TextArea.qml#n99) to `null`:

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480

    TextArea {
        placeholderText: qsTr("Search")
        focus: true
        background: null
        anchors.centerIn: parent
    }
}
```